# ROS Melodic catkin_make fail

Tags: ros, catkin, empy

So my `catkin_make` fails with error
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Interpreter'`
As I searched for a solution I found that the problem is that there is a confusion between the `em` and the `empy` packages, so I proceeded to remove the `em` package as advised, but the error still persists.

Answer (score 2):

You need to uninstall the em and install the empy package.

> pip uninstall em
>
> pip install empy